# Need to change Custom Page name in WordPress from "services" to "products"

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-pages

Have a wordpress Website in development a theme which has following url for a services

url for custom page type :

```
localhost/website/service/mechanical-engineering/
localhost/website/service/automotive-parts-systems/
```

need to change it to :

```
localhost/website/product/mechanical-engineering/
localhost/website/product/automotive-parts-systems/
```

I am not able to change it in permalinks, also i am a designer and know little about php

Have tried changing page name and tags in permalinks
also not able to find any plugin which can do this

Comment: This would need to be a post-launch thing but if you're using an Apache server maybe research how to add a rewrite rule to .HTACCESS.

Comment: @Shoelaced there are more than 35+ products can this be done from .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

You can change your post type slug using `register_post_type_args` filter.

try out these code in your theme functions.php.

```
function change_post_types_slug( $args, $post_type ) {
   /*item post type slug*/   
   if ( 'service' === $post_type ) {
      $args['rewrite']['slug'] = 'product';
   }
   return $args;
}
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'change_post_types_slug', 10, 2 );
```

Then save permalink Settings => permalink => save.

Comment: its not working, as there is no child theme adding this through code snippets plugin

Comment: Its not post i think its custom page type

Comment: what do you mean by custom page please explain. is it any page template Or generated using a plugin?  how you are adding a new service page?

Comment: Its a theme, its a page template. A create new service tab is there, similar to create new page. Its a custom theme. using Elementor.

Comment: check the add new service page url in admin is it look like `http://example.com/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=service` ?

Comment: @ziilionera_dev Yes it works it adds a new service - it is post type

Comment: @SachinDasar try adding the code in main theme's functions.php or create a child theme then add this in functions.php. code is tested and working. if your issue resolved then mark the answer as accepted.